# SQlite query with LIKE not working

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried some answers from stackoverflow, but i am still getting an error... Please some one tell me what's the problem and the solution...

```
public Cursor getSearchCursor(String query) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Cursor cd = notifdb.query(TABLE_NOTIFS, allColumns, COLUMN_NOTIF
                + " LIKE '%" + query + "%'", null, null, null, null);
        return cd;
    }
```

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific than "an error"? Wrong result? Exception?

Comment: java.lang.nullpointerexception is coming here... Is there a problem in the query, the syntax or something...??  PLease do tell me , i am stuck here...

Comment: check if any of the following are null: `notifydb`, `TABLE_NOTIFS`, `allColumns`, `COLUMN_NOTIF`, and `query`.

Comment: none of them are null... i dont know whats wrong... is the query allryt??

Comment: Can someone please guide me here??

Answer (score 0):

try this format...

```
        public Cursor getSearchCursor(String query) { 

            return db.query(true, DB_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_COLUMN1}, KEY_COLUMN1 + " LIKE" + "'%" + query + "%'", 
            null, null, null, null, null); 
        }
```